# How to enable IF condition on terrafrom modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I need to create TF CloudWatch Metrices only of the env is QAT and PROD. Currently using TF modules to create those in all env.

```
module "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" {
  source = "https://github.com/modules.git//aws-cloudwatch-log-metric-filter"
  log_group_name = "/aws/lambda/${var.lambda_name}"
  pattern = "{$.message = \"---------------- Message ----------------\"}"
}

locals {
  base_tags = {
    environment      = var.environment
  }
}
```

Main resource where I am calling module.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "log_metric" {
  count          = var.count
  name           = "Metric"
  pattern        = var.pattern
  log_group_name = var.log_group_name
    
  metric_transformation {
    name      = "name"
    namespace = "namespace"
      value     = "1"
      default_value = "0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in the module:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "log_metric" {
  count          = var.environment == "QAT" || var.environment == "PROD" ? 1 : 0
  name           = "Metric"
  pattern        = var.pattern
  log_group_name = "${var.environment}-${var.log_group_name}"

  metric_transformation {
    name      = "name"
    namespace = "namespace"
    value     = "1"
    default_value = "0"
  }
}
```

The `log_group_name = "${var.environment}-${var.log_group_name}"` will ensure you don't get issues with the same log group name.

Answer (score 1):

A simple but good solution :

```
locals {
  cw_env = ["QUA", "PROD"]
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "log_metric" {
  count          = contains(local.cw_env, var.env) ? 1 : 0
  name           = "Metric"
  pattern        = var.pattern
  log_group_name = var.log_group_name

  metric_transformation {
    name      = "name"
    namespace = "namespace"
    value     = "1"
    default_value = "0"
  }
}
```

Note you can also use it at the above level :

```
module "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" {
  source = "https://github.com/modules.git//aws-cloudwatch-log-metric-filter"

  count          = contains(local.cw_env, local.base_tags.environment) ? 1 : 0
  log_group_name = "/aws/lambda/${var.lambda_name}"
  pattern = "{$.message = \"---------------- Message ----------------\"}"
}

locals {
  base_tags = {
    environment      = var.environment
  }
  cw_env = ["QUA", "PROD"]
}
```

Comment: Let me try this.. Thank you much Sam